# JFreeChart XYAreaChart with negative values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to paint the area under the function that is always negative. How to do it? Now filled the area between the zero's and my function(the upper part of the screen) but i need to paint the bottom part.

like this:

[example of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXeiG.jpg)

If i use XYSeriesCollection with 2 series, then popups in bottom show values for second series, not for my function.

Comment: What does the colored area represent?

Comment: A forum [topic](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117702) cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17254737/230513) contrasts `XYDifferenceRenderer` & `XYAreaRenderer`.

Comment: @Atreys this is display for the spectrum analyser. Values is the signal level in dB, it looks strange when the signal is increasing from zero.